# why my screen width is wider than my actual screen width?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to use this:

```
@media screen (min-width: 300px) and (max-width:768px){
    body{display:none;}
}
```

but it doesn't work, when I check my screen width using `$(window).width()` then the result is `980` on google chrome responsive mode `320 x 700`. My question is why the result of `$(window).width()` is wider then my actual screen width ?

This is my screen shot
[image]

Comment: Can you post your code here, including your HTML and CSS?

Comment: The extra width can be caused by margin, padding, either of the element or of the browser's natural margin and paddings.

Comment: Please read: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: after a hours of searching the problem is im missing "<meta name=viewport content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1,user-scalable=no"/>"

Comment: @Myrealname That, plus `@media screen (min-width: 300px) and (max-width:768px)` is not correct. You need one more `and`.